# Why doesn't javadoc via ant show some of my method's doc?

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

i'm trying to generate some javadoc via ant for a small testproject but i don't really understand all of its behaviour. It seems that a lot of methods in my main class are left out and i don't really udnerstand why.

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Diese Methode deligiert die Ausfuehrung der zustandsabhaengigen Aktion an die entsprechende Methode
 * des Zustandsobjektes weiter, welches gerade in der Objektvariable zustand gespeichert ist.
 * @see SetMinutes
 * @see SetHours
 * @see DisplayTime
 */
 void inc(){
    zustand = zustand.inc(this);
 }
```

This one isn't shown. My ant target looks like this:

```
<target name="doc" depends="generateJar">
    <javadoc destdir="${doc.dir}">
            <fileset dir="."/>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

The only methods being shown are the main method (which is documented) and a run() method (empty). What makes me wonder as well is that my documentation for methods in the other classes of the project are generated properly and i can't see the difference.
(I have problems with generating a fields summary too but that's probably stuff for another question, isn't it?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `javadoc` command line option is `-protected`, which generates only `public` and `protected` methods.

To get package-private methods (as `inc()` is) you must specify `-package` or `-private`.

Oracle Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDCIFFD

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, with your help i was able to figure out what to do!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: to fit Stefan Bodewigs comment.

With the hint of Jim Garrison i was able to figure out the solution which is as follows (i will also sum up what was already said to have everything in one post):

- default command line option of javadoc is -protected which won't generate javadoc for private and package private fields and methods
- if one wishes to automate this via ant we can use 
  package="true" (or private="true" if one wishes to include those fields and methods, too)

Example:

```
<target name="doc" depends="generateJar"> <!--default option für javadoc ist -protected (siehe Web) daher fliegen im default package private methoden raus aus der doc-->
    <javadoc destdir="${doc.dir}" package="true">
            <fileset dir="."/>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Comment: actually you do not want to use `additionalparam` but rather `package="true"`.

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I will change my answer to fit this!

Comment: Thank you, looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

Change dirctory to the folder which contain your javacode.
Compile the code.
Then run the following Command.

```
javadoc -private -splitindex  <(compiledclassfilename)>.java
```